# I'm getting an error trying to retrieve data from google books api

Tags: android, json, api, google-books

I'm new to using API's in android, so I'm making a simple app using Google Books API, so I want to retrieve the title, author and description. This is the method that extracts the information but it throws the exception and executes the catch block. This is the query "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=1" where the bookJSON variable is the query response:

```
 private static List<Book> extractFeatureFromJson(String bookJSON) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(bookJSON)) {
            return null;
        }

                    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();


        try {

            // Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(bookJSON);


            JSONArray itemsArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");


            for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {

                           JSONObject currentBook = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONArray authorArray = currentBook.getJSONArray("authors");

                StringBuilder authorsStringBuild = new StringBuilder();

                for(int j=0; j<authorArray.length(); j++){
                    authorsStringBuild.append(authorArray.getString(j));
                    authorsStringBuild.append(", ");
                }

                String authors = authorsStringBuild.toString();

                String title = currentBook.getString("title");

                String description = currentBook.getString("description");

                double rating = currentBook.getDouble("averageRating");

                Book book = new Book( title, authors ,description , rating );

                books.add(book);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing the book JSON results", e);
        }

        return books;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do post the output and error logs in future. I did not have enough reputations to comment that. 
I ran your code and it's a JSON parsing error. 
Replace this line in your code

```
JSONArray authorArray = currentBook.getJSONArray("authors");
```

with this

```
itemsArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("volumeInfo").getJSONArray("authors");
```

you were missing the JSONobject before "authors".

You can use online JSON formatting tools to visualize the hierarchy better and make your life easier . This is the one I like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/